# Tool for writing articles

Tags: pdf, editors, tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Latex Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)

I need a tool to write my thesis. It should work with TeX, support multiple languages (want to publish this work in several languages), bibliographic references, create table of contents, and be able to export the result to pdf format. What editor do you use to create your articles?

Comment: Do you mean what text editor to use? Or what packages are worthwhile? Please make your question a little more specific. It's not clear what would count as an answer to this question.

Comment: I mean editor, yes.

Comment: Your parameters are still too broad, even accounting for your other comments until now. Perhaps it's time for some guided questioning. First, which computing environment are you most naturally comfortable with - Unix box, Mac, Windows? Next, would you count yourself highly comfortable with software programming - are you a seasoned programmer with aptitude or are you more of an end-user with a preference for ease-of-use software? Finally, can you afford to devote yourself to the steep curve of learning TeX/LaTeX etc, subtracting from research time, or instead prefer a minimum learning approach?

Comment: Linux. I'm comfortable with software programming, yes. Right now I cannot afford spending too much time learning TeX, but I will definitely do this in future.

Comment: Good, that nails things down quite a bit. I'm sure some great answers will be coming from the multilingual Linux experts super thick and fast. (Unfortunately, being mono-lingual and all things Windows, I'm disqualifying myself right now).

Comment: We already have a long list of editors and IDEs: [Latex Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)

Answer (score 4):

[Here is a nice comparison](http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/editors/) of various free editors.

But you should totally ignore it and just use emacs. I'm only half joking.

Comment: The OP said that he runs Linux as an OS, not emacs. ;p

Comment: No, you should totally ignore it and just use vim. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Mostly a matter of personal preferences. And of course the operating system. If you already have a favourite editor for other tasks, you may look after a LaTeX plug-in or something similar.

Language support is a feature of LaTeX itself, as well as the others you mentioned. You should be more specific. There are editors from basic functionality up to comfortable document management.

Comment: I just need something to begin with. Haven't worked with tex before, so I don't actually know, what I want.

Comment: In this case see »Comparison of TeX Editors« in the Wikipedia article about LaTeX.